# Global toolbars in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, class, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I would like to have a global toolbar at the top in each view of my tab bar controller (not dissimilar to the Facebook app) but I don't want to add a new one and write code for it each time. Is there any way to do this? I.e. Subclassing the toolbar class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using ViewController Containers which were officially introduced in iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want a *global* toolbar, that is the same for every view and not changing per-tab, then just create a new root controller that the toolbar and tab bar controller are both children of.

Comment: I'm using interface builder to do this, So I have a tab bar controller created using that. How would I embed this into a custom view as you mentioned?